# Using Selenium IDE, how to get the value of dynamic variable

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

i'm using selenium ide 2.8 and i'm trying to store values please find my below commands:

```
store | ayman | val1
store | 1 | n
store | val${n} | e
```

how to echo the value of **e** which is **ayman**? when i try :

```
echo | ${e}
```

i got echo | val1

what is the issue with my commands?

Thanks

Comment: You accepted an answer that wasn't correct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've done there the value of 'e' is not ayman, you have stored ayman as the variable 'val1'. I'm not 100% what you're trying to do here but it looks like you're trying to store 2 individual variables and then combine them as one as well. If that is the cast then what you'd need is this

```
store | ayman | val1
store | 1 | n
store | ${val1}${n} | e
```

in which case:

```
val1 = ayman
n = 1
e = ayman1
```

Comment: Hi Jsmith, i need the value of variable val depending on value of n; n will be 1,2,3 and so on. </br> now what i need to store the value of val${n} in variable e.

Comment: ok, I get what you're trying to do now but I don't think it's possible to create a variable containing another variable, besides I don't understand why you're doing it this way, as it's really over complicating it.

I'm assuming you'll have multiple variables (val1, val2 etc) just store them all and then call them as ${val1}, ${val2}  

Or if it's the case that only one of them will be in use at anyone time just store them all as val1 and make sure the one you're using for that test is last in the list

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to force an array type structure? val[1], val[2]?
Because what you want e to be is ${val${n}} right? Except that doesn't work.
you could do this in javascript though (with storeEval):
<tr>
 <td>storeEval</td>
 <td>storedVars['val'+storedVars['n']]</td>
 <td>final</td>
</tr>

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to force an array type structure? val[1], val[2]? Because what you want e to be is ${val${n}} right? Except that doesn't work. you could do this in javascript though (with storeEval):  storeEval storedVars['val'+storedVars['n']] final